# how to partner/bind items on different lists

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, generic-list

these are my declarations..

```
Public fList As New List(Of Form)
Dim mNameList As New List(Of String)
Dim mList As New List(Of GMapMarker)
Dim cList As New List(Of Integer)     'recently added code
Dim hList As New List(Of String)      'recently added code
```

this is my code where I add items on my list..

```
For Each dtrow In markerDtable.Rows
        marker = New GMapMarkerGoogleGreen(New PointLatLng(dtrow("Latitude"), dtrow("Longitude")))
        marker.ToolTipText = dtrow("MarkerName")

        mNameList.Add(dtrow("MarkerName"))
        cList.Add(dtrow("CameraID"))            'recently added code
```

*I really hope you get what I want to say..*
this is really hard for me. lol

anyway, as you can see, I add `elements` to my `List` for each data in my database. this code gives me the result that I need. Loads all the data (markers) on the map at `Form_Load`. If ever I add another data, (name,Lat,Lng) when form loads, viola another marker added on the map.

the List `mNameList` stands for the List of marker names not ID. just names..
onto the next code..

```
For Each m In mNameList
            For Each c In cList                    'recently added code
                If item.ToolTipText = m Then
                    Dim f As New Form2
                    fList.Add(f)
                    mList.Add(item)
                    With f
                        .Show()

                        .AxXHDec1.Camera = c       'recently added code
                        .AxXHDec1.Host = some ip   'recently added code

                        Dim p As New Point
                        p = item.LocalPosition + New Point(15, 30)
                        .Location = p
                        .Text = m
                    End With
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
Next
```

now this code, is on the `Marker_Click` event. SO, every time I click the marker, it shows me the forms added to `fList` then a corresponding condition that *that* form will show to a specific marker..
so if I have a marker named "Golf Club", form Golf Club will appear..

with that condition, I can bring out the form that I want to get.
back to the problem I am facing..

this is my database.. and `cList` must contain *CameraID*
so if things went smoothly, if I pull out `starmall` I should get the *starmall form* + the video feed from *Camera3*

[image]

**RESULT:** `OnMarker_Click` --> all markers I click, displays only Camera1.. though what I want is pull out the camera# depending on what *MarkerName/Form.Text* I am clicking..

**REMINDER:** *recently added code* -- means that that is the first attempt of me solving my solution. other codes are working perfectly. I just need some workaround.

this is *not google's API*.. I am using gmaps.net from codeplex.

**QUESTION:** how can I pull out the camera# in reference to the MarkerName?

ask questions for me to make it clearer for you.

Comment: Q1: `fList`, `cList` and `hList` are not populated, but are used in the code.   Q2: Do all the lists have equal number of items? that is, for each row in the dataTable, do you insert exactly-one item in all the lists?

Comment: all of the list at first, doesn't have values, their elements will come from the database which when form_loads. since all of them came from the db, they have the number of items. and each row, I add one until I have loaded all.

Answer (score 1):

note,

```
        For Each c In cList                    'recently added code
            If item.ToolTipText = m Then
```

you did not show where this `item` came from.

anyway, `ToolTipText` and `m` are both independent of cameraID `c`. hence the first c in `cList` will always match for all marker. That is why you get camera1.

---

I suggest a bit of code refactoring. you said that all the lists contain equal number of items, one each for one marker row in datatable. so, better make a small class say it `MarkerRow`.

```
class MarkerRow
    dim MarkerName as string
    dim cameraID as integer
    dim hostAddress as string

    dim marker as GMapMarker
end class
```

create only ONE list, make it of marker type rather than bunch of strings and integers

```
dim markers as new List(of MarkerRow)
```

now iterate over the datatable and fill ONE item each of one datarow

```
For Each dtrow In markerDtable.Rows
    dim marker = New GMapMarkerGoogleGreen(New PointLatLng(dtrow("Latitude"), dtrow("Longitude")))
    marker.ToolTipText = dtrow("MarkerName")

    dim markerRow = new MarkerRow
    with markerRow
        .MarkerName = dtrow("MarkerName")
        .cameraID = dtrow("CameraID")
        .hostAddress = dtrow("hostAddress")

        .marker = marker
    end with
next
```

this way, when you need a marker, you always have all the information at one place

```
dim m as MarkerRow = markers(0) ' or whatever by any criteria you like
```

then you will automaticaly have

```
m.cameraID
m.marker
m.markerName
```

and so on

Comment: thank you for the idea, I will explore with this first. seen something similar to this, still no luck. but let me try your solution.

Comment: in your line, `dim m as markerRow = markers(0)` I don't get what you are trying to imply. can you pls explain what it does?

Comment: see `markers` is a `List-of-MarkerRow` items. on `Marker_Click` event, you need to find out *which* marker was clicked on. how you find out is your concern. ex. you can use lat/long. once you find out which marker was clicked <#>, you loop through the `markers` collection and select the appropriate row. replace the *zero* in `markers(0)` with the serial number of the marker you found in step <#>.

Comment: there's something missing. `markers` doesn't have an item on it, since we didn't do something like `.add(dtrow("Latitude"))` in the code..

Comment: `dim marker = New GMapMarkerGoogleGreen(New PointLatLng(dtrow("Latitude"), dtrow("Longitude")))` so markers do have latitude and longitude information.

Comment: found what I am looking for, anyway, thanks for the help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513686/why-doesnt-it-add-to-the-list