# why doesn't it add to the list

Tags: .net, vb.net, generic-list

this question is based on this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511009/how-to-partner-bind-items-on-different-lists/20512063?noredirect=1#comment30665730_20512063)

I haven't found an answer, but I am trying on a solution and resulted to another question..

```
Public Class markerRow
  Public MarkerName As String
  Public CameraID As Integer
  Public HostAddress As String
End Class

Public mr As New markerRow
Dim aList As New List(Of markerRow)

For Each dtrow In markerDtable.Rows
        mr.MarkerName = dtrow("MarkerName")
        mr.CameraID = dtrow("CameraID")
        mr.HostAddress = dtrow("HostAddress")
        aList.Add(New markerRow())
Next
```

from what I think, this code should add every data from the DB to the respective variables in the list.. But I still don't know what it does exactly.

I checked the `aList.Count.ToString` and it gave me 5 items, which is true since I have 5 rows in my DB..

```
For Each elem In aList
        listbox.Items.Add(mr.MarkerName)
        listbox.Items.Add(mr.CameraID)
    Next
```

to check what items are in the `aList`, I did that.. unfortunately.. it only gives me the last item, 5 times. the last item on MarkerName Column and Camera ID Column.

[image]

What am I missing? or what's wrong in my code?
the `aList` should have what's on the DB above. not only the last item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public mr As New markerRow
Dim aList As New List(Of markerRow)

For Each dtrow In markerDtable.Rows
        mr.MarkerName = dtrow("MarkerName")
        mr.CameraID = dtrow("CameraID")
        mr.HostAddress = dtrow("HostAddress")
        aList.Add(New markerRow())
Next
```

Here, you are creating *one* `markerRow` named `mr`, and *update* it for every row in the `DataTable`. Also, for every row, you create *another* `markerRow`, and add that new one to `aList`.

```
For Each elem In aList
    listbox.Items.Add(mr.MarkerName)
    listbox.Items.Add(mr.CameraID)
Next
```

Then, for each element in `aList`, you add *two* items to the `ListBox`, and everytime it's `MarkerName` and `CameraID` from `mr`, and not the data from the elements of `aList`.

---

You're probably looking for something like:

```
Dim aList As New List(Of markerRow)

For Each dtrow In markerDtable.Rows 
    Dim mr = New markerRow() ' create a new markerRow for every row '
    mr.MarkerName = dtrow("MarkerName")
    mr.CameraID = dtrow("CameraID")
    mr.HostAddress = dtrow("HostAddress")
    aList.Add(mr)            ' add the new markerRow to the list '
Next

For Each elem In aList
    listbox.Items.Add(elem.MarkerName)
Next
```

Comment: great! thanks! I am really working my head now due to my problem on the previous link. :)